# Excel In Cell Formula, Number of Surveys Administered

Tags: excel-formula

Good Morning,

I have a large data set which details resident encounters we've had in our local community.  Sometimes during these encounters staff will collect survey data.  In order to track those survey results over time I need to assign each survey a survey number (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.).  I'm looking for a way to do this with an in cell formula.  Here's a data set as an example:

```
| Name         | Date Encountered | Q1 | Q2 | Stress | Survey Number |
|              |                  |    |    |        | (calculated)  |
|--------------|------------------|----|----|--------|---------------|
| Steve Rogers | 5/1/2018         | y  | y  | 5      | 2             |
| Steve Rogers | 4/16/2018        |    |    |        |               |
| Tony Stark   | 5/1/2018         | y  | y  | 1      | 2             |
| Nick Fury    | 5/3/2018         | y  | y  | 2      | 2             |
| Nick Fury    | 5/5/2018         | y  | y  | 8      | 3             |
| Tony Stark   | 5/2/2018         |    |    |        |               |
| Tony Stark   | 5/5/2018         | y  | y  | 3      | 3             |
| Steve Rogers | 4/1/2018         | y  | y  | 10     | 1             |
| Steve Rogers | 4/3/2018         |    |    |        |               |
| Nick Fury    | 4/15/2018        | y  | y  | 3      | 1             |
| Tony Stark   | 4/1/2018         | y  | y  | 5      | 1             |
```

As you may have noted above, there are two main complications in this data set.  1) the data isn't always sorted in chronological order, and 2) there may be days recorded when a survey wasn't administered.  With some help from others on this site (thanks Scott Craner!) I've come up with the following formula:

=IF(OR(C2 <> "", D2 <> "", E2 <> ""),COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "<=" & B2), "")

This is close, but doesn't quite do it right.  When I copy paste this down it leaves the cell blank if a survey wasn't administered (good), but it's not calculating the survey number correctly.  This is what's happening:

```
| Name         | Date Encountered | Q1 | Q2 | Stress | Survey Number |
|              |                  |    |    |        | (calculated)  |
|--------------|------------------|----|----|--------|---------------|
| Tony Stark   | 5/1/2018         |    |    |        |               |
| Tony Stark   | 5/2/2018         |    |    |        |               |
| Tony Stark   | 5/3/2018         | y  | y  | 10     | 3             |
| Tony Stark   | 5/5/2018         | y  | y  | 3      | 5             |
| Tony Stark   | 5/4/2018         | y  | y  | 5      | 4             |
```

Instead of the Survey Numbers being '3, 5, 4', I need it to be  '1, 3, 2'.  Any ideas what changes need to be made?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the not blank clause to `CountIfs()`:

`COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "<=" & B2, C:C, "<>", D:D, "<>", E:E, "<>")`

`=IF(OR(C2 <> "", D2 <> "", E2 <> ""),COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "<=" & B2, C:C, "<>", D:D, "<>", E:E, "<>"), "")`

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  Simple fix really